# How do I call Win32API SetCommTimeouts from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am having problems performing serial communications via the Win32 API from C#. No matter which values I use when calling SetCommTimeouts(), the call to ReadFile will not return unless one or more characters are received.

Using the .Net System.IO.Port.SerialPort class is not an option. It has serious bugs regarding USB-connected COM-ports which is the reason why I am trying to use the Win32 API directly instead.

Could the problem be with marshalling the CommTimeouts structure so that the API receives incorrect values?

Complete source code provided below:

```
namespace SerialTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

    [Flags]
    internal enum AccessRights : uint
    {
        GenericRead = (0x80000000),
        GenericWrite = (0x40000000),
        GenericExecute = (0x20000000),
        GenericAll = (0x10000000)
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum ShareModes : uint
    {
        FileShareRead = 0x00000001,
        FileShareWrite = 0x00000002,
        FileShareDelete = 0x00000004
    }

    internal enum CreationDispositions
    {
        CreateNew = 1,
        CreateAlways = 2,
        OpenExisting = 3,
        OpenAlways = 4,
        TruncateExisting = 5
    }

    internal class CommTimeouts
    {
        public UInt32 ReadIntervalTimeout;
        public UInt32 ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
        public UInt32 ReadTotalTimeoutConstant;
        public UInt32 WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier;
        public UInt32 WriteTotalTimeoutConstant;
    }

    internal class Kernel32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
            string lpFileName,
            uint dwDesiredAccess,
            uint dwShareMode,
            IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
            uint dwCreationDisposition,
            uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr hTemplateFile
        );

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCommTimeouts", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetCommTimeouts(SafeHandle hFile, CommTimeouts timeouts);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool ReadFile(SafeHandle hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
           uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
    }

    public class SerialTest
    {
        public void Test(string portName)
        {
            if (portName.Length > 5) portName = @"\\.\" + portName;
            var hPort = Kernel32.CreateFile(portName,
                                            (uint) (AccessRights.GenericRead | AccessRights.GenericWrite),
                                            0, // Not shared
                                            IntPtr.Zero, // Security attributes,
                                            (uint) CreationDispositions.OpenExisting,
                                            0,
                                            IntPtr.Zero // Template file
                );

            if (hPort.IsInvalid)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not open port " + portName + ". Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }

            try
            {
                // Set timeout so call returns immediately
                var timeouts = new CommTimeouts
                    {
                        ReadIntervalTimeout = 0xFFFFFFFF,
                        ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0,
                        ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0,
                        WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0,
                        WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0
                    };

                if (!Kernel32.SetCommTimeouts(hPort, timeouts))
                {
                    var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Exception("Could not set timeouts. Error: " + error.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));                    
                }

                var buf = new byte[1];
                uint readBytes;
                if (!Kernel32.ReadFile(hPort,
                                       buf,
                                       1,
                                       out readBytes,
                                       IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Exception("Could not read. Error: " + error.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                hPort.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling [`GetCommTimeouts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after the set to confirm your theory? Also while you're definitions are a little different to P/Invoke's ([here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/COMMTIMEOUTS.html) and [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetCommTimeouts.html)) I don't think that will make a difference.

Comment: It was the SetCommTimeouts definition which was incorrect. When set to [In] ref CommTimeouts it worked as expected.

I had copied the definition from an example I found and did not double check before using. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty important that you first identify the bug so you can avoid recreating it.  Had you done your homework, you'd have discovered that SerialPort is itself a thin wrapper that uses pinvoke.  So just use the [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/io/ports/SerialStream.cs,412) to get started.  Copy what's there, minus the bug :)

Answer (score 3):

The SetCommTimeouts definition which I found online was incorrect. Thanks to Richard, I now use the correct definition.

```
static extern bool SetCommTimeouts(IntPtr hFile, [In] ref COMMTIMEOUTS
lpCommTimeouts);
```